# nodeJs: implementing a one-time "channel" using promises

Tags: node.js

I want to have an async process wait for another async process to send it a signal. (once is enough)

in [Go](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2), you can create a channel between two processes.

```
def foo1(c chan int) {
   // do some stuff
   c <- 1
}

def foo2(c chan int) {
   <-c
   // do stuff later
}
```

basically `<-c` means, "wait until someone puts something in `c`". `c <- 1` means "put 1 in `c`". (assuming the same object `c` is passed to both functions).

I want to implement something similar with node. My Idea was to create a promise, and have one process resolve it, and the other to `await`. Something like:

```
function foo1(promise) {
   // do some stuff
   promise.resolve();
}

function foo2(promise) {
   await promise;
   // do stuff later
}
```

How can I do something like this?

Comment: Not quite is simple as that for interprocess communication I'm afraid, you'll find Go is wrapping up quite a lot under the hood with commands like `<-` `->`. There are various ways to achieve IPC with Node like using Sockets or raw TCP connections etc. Do some research.

Comment: Is a channel re-usable? What I mean is, can you write multiple things and read multiple things from it? If so, you may want something like a stream or an observable.

Comment: the processes are two node.js instances, or you mean inside a generic js file in a single process? Because in the first case you need IPC and in the second a promise could be ok (or an event emitter). I can provide you some better info

Comment: @PatrickRoberts channels are re-usable but I don't require re-usability for this discussion

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon two async methods launched in the same js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I found in the end:

```
async function foo1(resolveFn) {
  ...
  resolveFn();
  ...
}

async function foo2(promise) {
  ...
  await promise;
  ...
}

const promise = new Promise(resolve, reject) => {
  foo1(resolve);
});

await foo2(promise)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "https://www.npmjs.com/package/smem" to send data between async processes.

```js
// Import.
const SMem = require('smem');

// Create shared memory instance.
const defaultSMem = new SMem();
 
// Get value async.
(async () => {
  console.log(await defaultSMem.get('test-key'));
})();
 
// Set value after 2 seconds.
setTimeout(() => {
  defaultSMem.set('test-key', 'test-value');
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extend a [`PassThrough`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_passthrough) stream which implements the [`Transform`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_implementing_a_transform_stream) stream, and allows you to read and write arbitrary data in `objectMode`. Starting in Node v10, support for [`Symbol.asyncIterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/asyncIterator) was added to [streams](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_readable_symbol_asynciterator) and allows you to consume data from a [`Readable`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) stream using a [`for await...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of) loop, or manually by using the async iterator [`next()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of#Iterating_over_async_iterables), `return()`, and `throw()` methods, which return a `Promise<{ value, done }>`.

#### Extending `PassThrough`:

```
module.exports = class Channel extends require('stream').PassThrough {
  constructor () {
    super({ objectMode : true });
  }

  async * [Symbol.asyncIterator] () {
    const queue = [];
    const onData = data => { queue.push(data); };
    const next = resolve => {
      const onEvent = data => {
        this.off('data', onEvent);
        this.off('end', onEvent);
        resolve();
      };

      this.on('data', onEvent);
      this.on('end', onEvent);
    };

    this.on('data', onData);

    try {
      // internals of Readable; indicates whether end event was emitted
      while (!this._readableState.ended || queue.length > 0) {
        if (queue.length > 0) yield queue.shift();
        else await new Promise(next);
      }
    } finally {
      // unsubscribed in finally in case yield returns or throws
      this.off('data', onData);
    }
  }
};
```

Overriding the `[Symbol.asyncIterator]` method is optional, as it is already implemented on the `Readable` stream. However, the implementation above allows multiple concurrent sinks to consume the same data from the same instance of `Channel`, whereas the default implementation that exists on `Readable` does not allow concurrent sinks to consume the same data.

#### Usage:

```
const Channel = require('./channel');
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

// source
async function foo1 (c) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    await delay(500);
    console.log('foo1', i);
    c.write(i);
  }
  await delay(500);
  c.end();
}
// automatic
async function foo2 (c) {
  for await (const i of c) {
    console.log('foo2', i);
  }
}
// manual
async function foo3 (c) {
  const asyncIterator = c[Symbol.asyncIterator]();
  for (let data; !(data = await asyncIterator.next()).done; ) {
    console.log('foo3', data.value);
  }
}

const channel = new Channel();
foo1(channel);
// both can consume concurrently
foo2(channel);
foo3(channel);
```

#### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVRNU9swEL37VyynyIWaANNLU7iUHnroDFO4MQyjyGssRpZAH3EzkN@erizHcQZziaP9ePv0dlfPfMWdsPLFf9WmxK1Q3Dn4WXOtUQH@86hLBxZfg7TIZs5b5M0sL24o7K62JjzV8JYBCKPJF4Q3FljemQBceEHL3sAsn1H4P4QP34GiEDb5giI2Gf1wt9YCvsD97bpZGlV0598eLSeshz1YVwFeA1L6Jdw/LEZWo6@552Quu88VvKXA4iW4mkVjvoDNOEPT1SjeojNqhV1K590j/lqh9mPI3g/ga@kKU1VsFn2zk11wvpgIIf0mI/rKbDARvWycrD@FH/xT2DuYjyDXnQy9166HC52egtSkt@bKgangL/KSLxUuyFxKwT06aGv0NVqgioCdMC13gI30Hssep62lQmBHXeVH26PcegIoKA9LeH/v26JQP/karmCej3SVFbCP/rVEVfZ5rpaVZyMVUTkE3nIZO9rCjTWNdMhid/fCJl2gknRDdXDvoF1YxvFfEjuphxD6Kzghp9oWfbCatLGkqjWtyz6dg17jXdlNttmmeSpR8TVNU@PiLI25jkbQob@TDZrgd9YTSshj04isM8EKzNK@VEELLw1RNuYMmEg6VnH7FHqQVGpODYQfcBa/x8c7oZNYHR32bT7P90thFAlvntgsQtJt5M5XtFZ6ZLLf2WkMEXscW7OJXHnwpuFeigm65wd0ExZLKsk4f2K88WNS5wOpTarScB24mihxMZRIuAdvCkkjph@bNFmDiLGrCzhi6QXomR5kFHHQWJ4XpdG0L58RvyDiEaRYcRVwuEGWyIn@sb3sxqJ/eiOV2AfWe@lIF14a2grBdVchNBi/IlhLC6nWMf58FB8L74/b7X8)

---

If you don't care about re-usability, extending a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) is a *lot* easier:

```js
class PromiseCompletionSource extends Promise {
  static [Symbol.species] = Promise;

  constructor () {
    const completions = {};

    super(
      (resolve, reject) => Object.assign(completions, { resolve, reject })
    );

    this.resolve = completions.resolve;
    this.reject = completions.reject;
  }
}

function foo1 (c) {
  c.resolve(1);
  console.log('foo1');
}

async function foo2 (c) {
  console.log('foo2', await c);
}

function foo3 (c) {
  return c.then(i => {
    console.log('foo3', i);
  });
}

const channel = new PromiseCompletionSource();
foo1(channel);
foo2(channel);
foo3(channel);
```

The reason that `foo3` prints first is because `await c` is actually syntactic sugar for `Promise.resolve(c).then(...)`, not just `c.then(...)`, so `foo3()` delays the resolved value by one less tick than `foo2()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to accomplish this task is using `EventEmitter`.

This works from Node 11.13 (the `once` function is in that version):

```
'use strict'

const { EventEmitter, once } = require('events')

const sharedEventEmitterChannel = new EventEmitter()

async function foo1 () {
  console.log('do some stuff')
  await heavyTask()
  sharedEventEmitterChannel.emit('myevent', 1)
  console.log('emitted')
}

async function foo2 () {
  try {
    const num = await once(sharedEventEmitterChannel, 'myevent')
    console.log('do stuff later', num)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

foo2()
foo1()

function heavyTask () {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
}
```

For early version of node:

```
'use strict'

const { EventEmitter } = require('events')

const sharedEventEmitterChannel = new EventEmitter()

async function foo1 () {
  console.log('do some stuff')
  await heavyTask()
  sharedEventEmitterChannel.emit('myevent', 1)
  console.log('emitted')
}

async function foo2 () {
  sharedEventEmitterChannel.once('myevent', (num) => {
    console.log('do stuff later', num)
  })
}

foo2()
foo1()

function heavyTask () {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
}
```